# C++ Warming std vector

Tags: c++, std, stdvector

Why filling std::vector second time is FASTER? Even if space was reserved from the beggining?

```
int total = 1000000;

struct BaseClass {
  float m[16];
  int id;

  BaseClass(int _id) { id = _id; }
};

int main() {

  std::vector<BaseClass> ar;
  ar.reserve(total);

  {
    auto t_start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (int var = 0; var < total; ++var) {
      ar.emplace_back(var);
    }
    auto t_end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(
                     t_end - t_start).count() << "\n";
    ar.clear();
  }

  {
    auto t_start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (int var = 0; var < total; ++var) {
      ar.emplace_back(var);
    }
    auto t_end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(
                     t_end - t_start).count() << "\n";
    ar.clear();
  }

  {
    auto t_start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (int var = 0; var < total; ++var) {
      ar.emplace_back(var);
    }
    auto t_end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(
                     t_end - t_start).count() << "\n";
    ar.clear();
  }

  return 0;
}
```

online preview:
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/229e4ba47adddb1a

**RESULTS**:
118
23
21

P.S. I'm asking why it becomes faster if the only reason for slowdown for vector is allocation/reallocation. And we allocated array BEFORE start.

Comment: Because your tests are not independent.. the first run will have put the contents into cache, and the second run then doesn't have to write anything to memory.

Comment: you are using `emplace_back` the wrong way, `emplace_back` is supposed to build an object "in place", you are not even casting `var` with `std::move`, what are you trying to do exactly ?

Comment: @user2485710 - I build a bunch of objects on the fly in vector. Than I do the same again. Why first time slower?

Comment: @Thomas - why it will put on the cache? What kind of cache? Here is example with "different" objects http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/846574197d41ca4f

Comment: @Thomas:  It may have also triggered getting the memory from the OS.  `reserve()` might have gotten permission to have pages of memory, but actually touching them would fault them in.  @tower120:  The processor's hardware memory cache.

Comment: Post the program results here, why do you use external links for 3 numbers?

Comment: because it's also the first and only point where you really allocate memory for your vector, that's what `reserve` does and even if you use it 3 times, it only really works for the first invocation.

Comment: @user2485710 But `reserve` is put outside of the measurement points. So that's not it. Unless there is some kind of lazy allocation.

Comment: @Joe Z - My notebook cache is about 1Mb and I got the same results. No matter how big array is.

Comment: @luk32 http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/clear note the phrase "Leaves the capacity() of the vector unchanged." and click on the link to `capacity()` after that.

Comment: @luk32:  Most OSes implement lazy allocation.  If you call `malloc` or `new` and ask for some large amount of memory (beyond the current heap), and the C run time asks the kernel for the space, the kernel notes it down and says "Yeah, sure."  It's not until the program tries to access those pages and incurs page faults that the OS goes and finds the memory to give to the task.

Comment: @user2485710, luk32 - it HAS TO ALLOCATE http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/reserve/ "If n is greater than the current vector capacity, the function causes the container to reallocate its storage increasing its capacity to n (or greater)."

Comment: @tower120 and since your `total` variable is always the same, you are effectively allocating space only the first time you call `reserve`, really there is no black magic in this.

Comment: @user2485710 - YES! It IS ALLOCATED FIRST time! WHY than, first time filling is slower than the second one? If and 1st and 2nd time we ALREADY have allocated storage.

Comment: `reserve` is outside of the measurement. It's not important what's in there. My point is, the extra work must be done elsewhere. user2485710 - Your logic is flawed. And tower120, no it does not have to `reserve` space in the very call, as @JoeZ neatly explained. And to me that would a nice explanation what is happening.

Comment: @luk32 Where I said that it has to be reserved each time? I'll edit code now. It seems this interfere to see the essence.

Comment: @tower120 You don't get my point. Where did I say you said it reserves memory time 3 times.  Please... Even if it did, `reserve/clear` are outside of measurement. I am saying, the memory is not physically reserved when you call `reserve`, but when you 1st access it. That is why some of the allocation time actually slips into measurement.

Comment: @luk32 I really don't get **your** logic, I think that if you really thing that everything is going as expected, it may be that `std::chrono` internals are `static`, so the call to `std::chrono` triggers an allocation the first time giving you a false reading.

Comment: Look at the JoeZ's answer. OS takes more time on the 1st access of allocated memory.

Comment: @luk32 - "I am saying, the memory is not physically reserved when you call reserve" Where do you read that? As for me, specification clearly says ALLOCATION. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/reserve/

Comment: @tower120 That's "allocation" in the sense of the allocator being used. It doesn't mean the OS is required to immediately make some physical memory available.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The reason that the first run is slower than the other two is that the runtime has not yet gotten the memory pages from the OS.

I instrumented your program to output the number of major and minor page faults the task had taken at the beginning, and after each of the three stages above.  (Note: This works on Linux.  No idea if it'll work on whatever OS you're on.)  Code:

<sup>**Note:** updated to latest, with `reserve()` moved to the top and wrapped in its own `getrusage` call.</sup>

```
#include <ctime>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>

using namespace std;

int total = 1000000;

struct BaseClass {
  float m[16];
  int id;

  BaseClass(int _id) { id = _id; }
};

int main() {

  std::vector<BaseClass> ar;
  struct rusage r;
  {
    auto t_start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
     }

  getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &r);
  cout << "minflt: " << r.ru_minflt << " majflt: " << r.ru_majflt << endl;

  ar.reserve(total);

  getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &r);
  cout << "minflt: " << r.ru_minflt << " majflt: " << r.ru_majflt << endl;

  {
    auto t_start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (int var = 0; var < total; ++var) {
      ar.emplace_back(var);
    }
    auto t_end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(
                     t_end - t_start).count() << "\n";
    ar.clear();
  }

  getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &r);
  cout << "minflt: " << r.ru_minflt << " majflt: " << r.ru_majflt << endl;

  {
    auto t_start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (int var = 0; var < total; ++var) {
      ar.emplace_back(var);
    }
    auto t_end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(
                     t_end - t_start).count() << "\n";
    ar.clear();
  }

  getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &r);
  cout << "minflt: " << r.ru_minflt << " majflt: " << r.ru_majflt << endl;

  {
    auto t_start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (int var = 0; var < total; ++var) {
      ar.emplace_back(var);
    }
    auto t_end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(
                     t_end - t_start).count() << "\n";
    ar.clear();
  }

  getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &r);
  cout << "minflt: " << r.ru_minflt << " majflt: " << r.ru_majflt << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

I then ran it on my box.  The result is enlightening:

```
minflt: 343 majflt: 0
minflt: 367 majflt: 0
48    minflt: 16968 majflt: 0
16
minflt: 16968 majflt: 0
15
minflt: 16968 majflt: 0
```

Notice that the first measured for-loop incurred over 16,000 minor faults.  Those faults are what make the memory available to the application and account for the slower running time.  No additional faults happen thereafter.  In contrast, the `reserve()` call itself only incurred 24 minor faults.

In most modern virtual-memory OSes, the OS implements lazy memory allocation, even if the software running on it does not.  When the runtime requests additional memory from the OS, the OS makes a note of the request.  If the request succeeds, the runtime now has a new range of virtual addresses available to it.  (Details vary depending on the API called and the OS, but the essence is the same.)  The OS may point the virtual address range to a single zero-filled page marked read-only.

The OS does *not* necessarily make those pages immediately available to the task.  Rather, the OS waits until the task actually tries to write to the memory it's allocated.  At that point, the OS allocates a physical page to back the virtual page allocated to the task.  That registers as a "minor fault" in UNIX parlance.  That process can be expensive.

It's that lazy allocation that your task is measuring.

To prove that, I did an `strace` of the application as well.  The meaningful portion is below.

```
getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, {ru_utime={0, 0}, ru_stime={0, 0}, ...}) = 0
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 0), ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fe3aa339000
write(1, "minflt: 328 majflt: 0\n", 22) = 22
mmap(NULL, 68001792, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fe3a551c000
getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, {ru_utime={0, 0}, ru_stime={0, 0}, ...}) = 0
write(1, "minflt: 352 majflt: 0\n", 22) = 22
write(1, "52\n", 3)                     = 3
getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, {ru_utime={0, 30000}, ru_stime={0, 20000}, ...}) = 0
write(1, "minflt: 16953 majflt: 0\n", 24) = 24
write(1, "20\n", 3)                     = 3
getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, {ru_utime={0, 50000}, ru_stime={0, 20000}, ...}) = 0
write(1, "minflt: 16953 majflt: 0\n", 24) = 24
write(1, "15\n", 3)                     = 3
getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, {ru_utime={0, 70000}, ru_stime={0, 20000}, ...}) = 0
write(1, "minflt: 16953 majflt: 0\n", 24) = 24
munmap(0x7fe3a551c000, 68001792)        = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
```

As you can see, the task allocated memory with an `mmap` call between the first two `getrusage` system calls.  And yet, that step only incurred 24 minor faults.  So, even though C++ was *not* being lazy, Linux was being lazy about giving the memory to the task.

Specifically, the first `mmap` call appears to allocate an I/O buffer for the first `write` mesage.  The second `mmap` call (allocating 68001792 bytes) happens *before* the second `getrusage` call.  And yet, you can see only 24 additional faults occurred between the two on this run.

The hawk-eyed among you will notice the numbers are slightly different for this run than the numbers I showed above.  I've run this executable many times, and the numbers shift slightly each time.  But, they're always in the same general ballpark.

Comment: during the cheat-chat another consideration came to my mind: it's possible that the variables triggered by the call to `std::chrono` are `static` ? This will explain why they slow things down ( indirectly ) the first time.

Comment: It's possible they have a first-use penalty, although that could be easily ruled out by measuring a dummy section just before the first section.

Comment: I also think that this thing depends more on the `allocator` than on the container itself, this also means that the answer to this question can change based on the type of allocator that you choose for your `std::vector`. the paging is a behaviour that is extremely OS-specific.

Comment: @user2485710 : Whenever the total process virtual memory size increases, the OS has to give you pages, regardless of the `allocator`.  The `allocator` will matter more in a long-running process that has a stable resident working set size.

Comment: @Joe Z - please look MY updated code http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/229e4ba47adddb1a. And move out "reserve" from your measures. We want to see "emplace_back" results only.

Comment: not always, with the so called "pool allocators" it's not exactly like that.

Comment: @JoeZ Well the allocator could *touch* the page. I even saw things like that implemented for multithreaded applications. When you wanted your memory pinned to a processor. You had to use `malloc` and then parallel `for` that would write `0` or whatever, so the system would allocate page physically close to the process that would work over the same area later. If you used only 1 CPU, system would allocated pages close only to this one, which would screw access times and syncronization for actual calculations.

Comment: @luk32: That's true, it could touch the page, fair enough.  In fact, I've written such loops for that purpose.  I guess I never thought of that being the job of the allocator, but rather the consumer of the allocated memory, but you're right.

Comment: @tower120 : I looked at your updated code and modified mine to have a single `reserve()` call at the top with a `getrusage()` before and after it.  `reserve()` triggered only 24 minor faults.  The rest of the results didn't change meaningfully—they were all within the normal run-to-run jitter.

Comment: @Joe Z Seems to be true. But where you read about that lazy memory allocation? Please update your answer with this, and with that thing about result().

Comment: @tower120 : Note that C++ isn't being lazy, Linux is being lazy.  I'll post more in a moment.

Comment: @Joe Z Windows being lazy too. And OsX being lazy too, as it Linux base. So all beings lazy (human - especially :) ). They (c++ committee) had to add some tehnique to prevent this, or at least descibe this.

Comment: @tower120 : Actually OS X is BSD-based under the hood, not Linux based.  But, lazy allocation is the what most virtual memory OSes default to.  Real time tasks and real time OSes usually aren't so lazy.  Anyway, I put some more interesting data up there in my answer, showing `strace` results to highlight the fact that C++ isn't being lazy but the kernel is.

Comment: But where it can be read about lazy allocation memory model? I would like to read about this in some specification :)

Comment: @tower120 : It isn't really in any C++ language specification anywhere.  Go read up on virtual memory operating systems.

Comment: @Joe Z - I asked about OS/memory model specification:) So... where to go? :)

Comment: @tower120 : You won't find a specification, _per se_.  But, this page seems to be a good introduction to the topics:  http://www.cs.uic.edu/~jbell/CourseNotes/OperatingSystems/9_VirtualMemory.html  For something more than that, google these terms with respect to your favorite OS.  How each OS does it is specific to the OS and the details can change version to version.  The three concepts were at play in this topic:  Demand paging, copy-on-write and zero-fill-on-demand.

Comment: @tower120 : You can find some additional details buried in Ulrich Drepper's "What Every Programmer Should Know About Memory," in section 7.5 among others.  Reading the whole thing is enlightening, though.  http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/cpumemory.pdf